# Comment dit-on « Welcome back! » ?

Tags: salutations

J'ai cherché dans deux dictionnaires et je n'ai pas trouvé une façon de dire « *Welcome back !* ». C'est ce qu'on dit quand quelqu'un qu'on a déjà vu revient à un endroit. Est-ce qu'on ne le dit pas en français ?

Comment: Tout dépend du contexte, en français ça dépend de la situation dans laquelle on le dit. [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/welcome%20back) propose des traductions mais, c'est le genre expression pour lesquelles je préfère chercher sur [linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/welcome+back.html).

Comment: J'avoue être très surpris de trouver une proposition de fermeture de la discussion au motif *too broad*. Je trouve au contraire la question bien délimitée, intéressante, et pertinente. Non ? Un idiome courant en anglais sans équivalent français exact, ça doit être une question que d'autres personnes se sont posées, mais en l'occurrence elle n'est pas sans réponse donc...

Comment: @RomainVALERI. Je pense m'être clairement expliquée. je ne demande jamais une fermeture sans donner la raison. 
"Tout dépend du contexte, en français ça dépend de la situation dans laquelle on le dit". Il est donc clair que je demande **du contexte**. Et pour expliquer ce que je veux dire je renvoie le PO vers linguee où il pourra apprécié les différents contextes.  Si nous voulons des questions de bonne qualité il est important de donner des pistes pour que les questions soient mieux posées et que ceux qui les posent fassent un minimum de recherche d'eux mêmes.

Comment: Et une claque sur la main pour Romain qui n'avait pas compris le commentaire de fermeture ;-) Ok, Laure, désolé c'est plus clair comme ça.

Comment: @Laure « il pourra apprécié » mérite aussi une claque sur la main ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre: Même venant de quelqu'un qui ne fait jamais de faute de frappe ou de faute d'orthographe ce commentaire reste disgracieux. Je suppose que si la fonction correction dans les commentaires était permise tu aurais corrigé...

Comment: @Laure C'était bien sûr au deuxième degré d'où l'émoticône. Je suis le premier à regretter l'intransigeance de stackexchange sur les éditions de commentaires ainsi d'ailleurs que l'impossibilité de modifier une question ou une réponse si le changement ne porte pas sur un nombre suffisant de caractères.

Comment: @jlliagre … Commentaire avec Pb : copier. créer nouveau, coller, corriger, effacer l’erroné …  pas terrible ? peut-être, mais on se sent mieux après :-)

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL Hmm, il y a six ans que j'ai écrit ça ! Mais oui, c'est ce que je fais souvent sauf que ce n'est pas la solution s'il y déjà eu une réponse au commentaire à corriger.

Comment: @jlliagre, alors, peut-être, laisser le premier commentaire et ajouter ***Rectificatif commentaire précédent*** (ou autre "tire l’œil") sur le second … pas jojo, mais honnête.

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL Ouais... sinon, y'a aussi l'option "devenir modérateur" car on peut alors sûrement éditer les commentaires, mais bon, je ne suis pas du tout tenté...

Comment: @jlliagre Shuuut … sinon nos commentaires vont disparaître !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Non, il me semble bien que c'est quelque chose qui ne se formule pas de cette manière spécifique en français. En tout cas pas de manière littérale. On trouve cependant des usages proches. Quelques exemples ci-dessous.

Quand un membre d'un groupe quitte ce groupe puis le réintègre par exemple, on peut imaginer :

> Content de te revoir !

...qui accentue l'aspect affectif de la situation, ou

> Heureux de te revoir parmi nous !

qui est plus formel et ne conviendrait pas dans un contexte détendu. En revanche, si cette fois le contexte est familier, et qu'on veut simplement donner un bref acquiescement amical au retour de quelqu'un, il existe aussi le minuscule :

> Re ! (abréviation extrême d'un probable *Re-bonjour / Re-salut / Re-bienvenue*)

Mais comme je l'ai dit, la liste n'est pas exhaustive, et ce ne sont que des sens proches, non des traductions exactes.

Comment: Jules ! Le retour !

Answer (score 7):

Je propose:

> Bon retour parmi nous!

Le simple *bon retour* est plus souvent adressé à quelqu'un qui s'en va.

Comment: (+1) Ah oui je l'avais oublié mais c'est utilisé aussi, ça. Bien vu.

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenu chez toi, au plaisir de te revoir, quel plaisir de te revoir

Answer (score 0):

Rebienvenu!

Je blague, mais ça me semble bien en logique de français.